# How to use mod_register module on a specific port in Ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

How to use mod_register in Ejabberd on some port for making registerations in Ejabberd?

Answer (score 0):

`mod_register` is just an IQ handler. It implements [xep-77](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html).

So u only need send an IQ request in client to do registerations.